# How to add multiple include path to task.json?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug this repository: [MP-SPDZ](https://github.com/data61/MP-SPDZ), in which many `.h`, `.hpp` and `.cpp` files are placed in various folders. Additionally, in each `.cpp` file, several header files are included.

To be clearer here is what the file tree looks like :

```
  >ProjectTP
      >Machines
          -mascot-party.cpp
          -SPDZ.cpp
          -SPDZ.hpp
          -Player-Online.cpp
          -Player-Online.hpp
          -more files ...
      >Processor
          -Machine.h
          -Machine.hpp
          -more files ...
      >More folders ...
```

Note that in some cases `.hpp` files are considered as `.h` files while for some other cases they are considered a `.cpp` files. The problem is when I try to compile the project, VS Code is not able to find the headers, while I added all the include path to `task.json`.

Here is my main `.cpp` file `(mascot-party.cpp)` that is placed in a folder called `Machines` in the root directory.

```
#include "Player-Online.hpp"
#include "Math/gfp.hpp"
#include "GC/TinierSecret.h"

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    ez::ezOptionParser opt;
    return spdz_main<Share<gfp>, Share<gf2n>>(argc, argv, opt);
}
```

This is `Player-Online.hpp` that is included in `(mascot-party.cpp)` (Just to show how nested the repository is)

```
#include "Processor/Machine.h"
#include "Processor/OnlineOptions.h"
#include "Math/Setup.h"
#include "Protocols/Share.h"
#include "Tools/ezOptionParser.h"
#include "Networking/Server.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T, class U>
int spdz_main(int argc, const char** argv, ez::ezOptionParser& opt, bool live_prep_default = true)

...
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my `task.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Machines/mascot-party.cpp",
                //"${workspaceFolder}/Machines/SPDZ.cpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Tools/*.cpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Math/*.cpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/OT/*.cpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Networking/*.cpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Processor/*.cpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Protocols/*.cpp",

                "${workspaceFolder}/Machines/*.hpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Tools/*.hpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Math/*.hpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/OT/*.hpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Processor/*.hpp",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Protocols/*.hpp",

                "-Idir",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Processor",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Tools",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Math",
                "${workspaceFolder}/OT",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Networking",
            
                
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

This is the compiler error:
[image]

**Important note:** When I put the absolute path in my .cpp files (e.g. instead of `#include "Processor/Machine.h"` I put `#include "/home/user/MP-SPDZ_VSCode/Processor/Machine.h"`) it finds the headers. However, the repository is huge, and it's not possible to fix it this way.

I tried many different configurations for so long, but no result. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the file `c_cpp_properties.json` is not the correct place to set your `include` directories. According to [its reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference):

> `includePath` An include path is a folder that contains header files
> (such as `#include "myHeaderFile.h"`) that are included in a source
> file. Specify a list of paths for the IntelliSense engine to use while
> searching for included header files.

So most likely this is used just for intellisense.

You safest bet is in my opinion to specify the include paths in the compiler command, which you are already setting up manually in `task.json`. In the property `args` try adding the argument `-Idir` and then the path to the directory that contains the directory `Processor`:

```
"args": [
    ...
    "-Idir",
    "${fileDirname}/../dir-that-contains-the-Processor-dir
    ...
]
```

Comment: @ Lyubomir Vasilev Thank you. I added the flag "Idir" before the include paths in task.json. However, the error is the same.                                   
                                "-Idir",
    "${fileDirname}/*.h", ... , 
    "${fileDirname}/../Processor/*.h",

Comment: You need to specify a directory, not file like `*.h`. Try using simply something like `"${fileDirname}/.."` - it seems like this is where the directory `Processor` is located.

Comment: @ Lyubomir Vasilev, Ah right. I removed the * .h and only passed: "-Idir", "${fileDirname}/..,    ...,    "${fileDirname}/../Processor". Still its not finding the headers.